# How do you get key frames made from objects automatically following paths?

Tags: animation, keyframes, procedural

I am trying to keyframe a ball that is following a path automatically using a driver. The camera is stationary. I can't seem to get the automatic key framer to work?

Comment: Try baking the keyframes.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. How do you do that?

Comment: I have done it thankyou for any other noobs out there you press F3 and 'Bake action' and its done.

Comment: ## Check this link, the video talks about automatic keyframing ##
https://youtu.be/GFjgquT8f5w